# Check if javascript library exist using chrome extension

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making an extension and will be modifying active tab's HTML & will also inject some JS library, but before that, I want to check if certain library is already present in that tab or not, if already present then it might create problems with my injecting JS library e.g;

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: '/javascript/angular.min.js'});
});
```

before injecting this I want to know if current site already have this library or not.

Comment: Extentions run on a different realm. You don't have to worry about it. Just make sure you load the library with the extension. This is what I've done with an extension I've developed a while ago. If this is the right thing to do? I don't know, but I never had problems before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do that, original js library which exists in the web page won't affect your extension.

Take a look at [Execution environment](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment),

> Content scripts execute in a special environment called an isolated world. They have access to the DOM of the page they are injected into, **but not to any JavaScript variables or functions created by the page.** It looks to each content script as if there is no other JavaScript executing on the page it is running on. The same is true in reverse: **JavaScript running on the page cannot call any functions or access any variables defined by content scripts.**